How to set up a Lambda Layer for Ruby's mysql2 library?
I've been trying to set up a Lambda Layer for my Ruby Lambda function but I can't make it work for some reason.
I've followed AWS' tutorial on creating (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/ruby-layers.html) but for mysql2, the library that I'm trying to install, it does not work.
I understand that there are some dependencies that might cause this issue.
When I run my function, I get the following error message:
"errorMessage": "libmariadb.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory - /opt/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/mysql2-0.5.6/lib/mysql2/mysql2.so"
EDIT: This lambda function should be able to run queries on an RDS DB that is a MySQL instance.
How can I install this lambda layer? What kind of file should I package into my layer besides the gem themselves?
I've tried copying the libmariadb.so.3 file to my layer folder in the way that the structure stays like this: ruby/libs and ruby/gems in the same level.The /libs folder is the one that I've saved libmariadb.so.3. It did not work, I've got the same error.

does your code function locally?

This can occurs because AWS Lambda’s Ruby runtime environment doesn’t include the native libraries required by the mysql2 gem by default.
To better fix this issue, try always to test wether your code works or no in amazonlinux:2 image, to make sure about the computability beforehand. If things works out, then try to create the layer from that image also, because installing stuff on different systems may install different things that will not work out on the lambda.
This is how i would do it if i was in your place:
docker run -it amazonlinux:2
yum install -y gcc make ruby ruby-devel mariadb-devel
gem install bundler
mkdir -p /lambda/ruby/gems/3.3.0
cd /lambda
BUNDLE_PATH=/lambda/ruby/gems/3.3.0 bundle add mysql2
docker cp <container_id>:/lambda ./lambda-layer
docker cp <container_id>:/usr/lib64/libmariadb.so.3 ./lambda-layer/ruby/lib/
cd lambda-layer
zip -r layer.zip .

This is the best way to ensure that the compiled library (libmariadb.so.3) is compatible with the runtime environment.
also it may be permission issue, and you need to just to update the permission before creating the zip and upload it chmod -R 755 ruby/lib
